# How to select distinct records in PSQL based on the latest date/record?

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a query in PostgreSQL that is joining multiple tables, but one table (TABLE_D) has multiple records per table, and I only want to pull in the latest record based on a single field (DATE_ACTION) in the table. So, in the example here, I would only want to pull in the record boxed in green because that one displays the most recent DATE_ACTION value. I'm trying to figure out how to set up the query to only pull in this one record and the other four records should not be displayed. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cd9QF.png)

Below is my basic query. I tried adding DISTINCT to the Select statement, but that's not working. I want distinct records based on ORDER_NO, RECORD_NO, PART, MUST_DLVR_BY_DATE, JOB and SUFFIX. Then attached to that, I want to see the most recent DATE_ACTION value.

```
select A.ORDER_NO, A.RECORD_NO, B.PART,  A.MUST_DLVR_BY_DATE, C.JOB, C.SUFFIX, D.DATE_ACTION, A.DATE_SHIPPED
from TABLE_A A
inner join TABLE_B B on A.ORDER_NO=B.ORDER_NO and A.RECORD_NO=B.RECORD_NO
inner join TABLE_C C on A.ORDER_NO=C.SALES_ORDER and left(A.RECORD_NO,3)=C.SALES_ORDER_LINE
left join TABLE_D D on C.JOB=D.JOB and C.SUFFIX=D.SUFFIX
where  B.DATE_SHIP in ('','000000') and D.DATE_ACTION <>'' and A.must_dlvr_by_date <> '00000000' and D.code_transaction = 'J52'
order by A.ORDER_NO, A.RECORD_NO, D.DATE_ACTION DESC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use DISTINCT ON clause along with the ORDER BY clause to sort the records. Something like this:

```
WITH ranked_records AS (
    SELECT 
        A.ORDER_NO, 
        A.RECORD_NO, 
        B.PART, 
        A.MUST_DLVR_BY_DATE, 
        C.JOB, 
        C.SUFFIX, 
        D.DATE_ACTION, 
        A.DATE_SHIPPED,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.ORDER_NO, A.RECORD_NO ORDER BY D.DATE_ACTION DESC) AS row_num
    FROM TABLE_A A
    INNER JOIN TABLE_B B ON A.ORDER_NO = B.ORDER_NO AND A.RECORD_NO = B.RECORD_NO
    INNER JOIN TABLE_C C ON A.ORDER_NO = C.SALES_ORDER AND LEFT(A.RECORD_NO, 3) = C.SALES_ORDER_LINE
    LEFT JOIN TABLE_D D ON C.JOB = D.JOB AND C.SUFFIX = D.SUFFIX
    WHERE B.DATE_SHIP IN ('', '000000')
        AND D.DATE_ACTION <> ''
        AND A.must_dlvr_by_date <> '00000000'
        AND D.code_transaction = 'J52'
)
SELECT * FROM ranked_records WHERE row_num = 1;
```

Comment: Based on everything else I've researched, it looks like that solution should work, but when I run the query using the DISTINCT ON clause with the ORDER BY clause, I'm getting a syntax error: "[PSQL][SQL Engine]Syntax Error: SELECT DISTINCT ON<< ??? >>" I can't figure out what's causing this.

Comment: i updated the answer with a more universal approach.

Comment: @PJT1991: if you get an error using the original answer `distinct on ()` you are not using Postgres